# Chrome Extension is published to testers. How do they access it?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I published to testers about 36 hours ago. After that long, it shouldn't be a time thing, right? it does say "Status: Published to testers" so I'd think it would work. But I can't figure it out.

I poked around here and found a couple of posts with possibilities but they haven't worked.

here is what I've tried. both get me a 404 error

1. Manual creation of store link (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ID = 404
2. Clicking the hyperlink title on the store listing page in my developer dashboard. = 404.
3. Cleared cache & cookies

all I want is a link to share with my testers! the webstore doesn't seem to like that idea.
I'd love suggestions on what else to try.

Thank you!

Tried:

Comment: Make sure you add your testers' email accounts in the Chrome Web Store dashboard, in the section Account - Management - Trusted tester accounts

Comment: I did that right when I published it to testers.  there's still no way to get a link.